# Use relative file path with LoadImage

Tags: c++, winapi

I am attempting to load a file from a relative file path in win32 via the `LoadImage` function. The URL I am using definitely exists as I am, for testing purposes, using the same URL as an added bitmap in the resource file.

```
Image = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, "..\\..\\Images\\Mage default.bmp",
                           IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

However, it is returning error code 2, indicating the file can't be found. I have googled the issue at some length, and referred to MSDN, and I can't find anything stating how to use a relative file path with `LoadImage`.

It seems to work fine with `LoadBitmap` and a pre-defined bitmap, but doesn't seem to work in this case. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Backward relative addressing isn't recommended in many cases. It complicates the managing paths for the programmer.

Comment: Relying on the default working directory being set right never stops hurting.  And this just won't work when it runs on the user's machine in the normal install location.  No c:\program files\images directory.  Generate absolute path names from GetModuleFileName(), passing NULL to find out where the EXE is stored.

Comment: @HansPassant OK, thank you very much. It should be easy to generate the absolute file path by combining the relative and the absolute path generated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, check that the file exist and current directory is the one you expected.

Also, you can use function like [GetFullPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert relative path to absolute.

Comment: GetFullPathName returns the wrong value when attempting to get the absolute path

Comment: I think the bug is not in GetFullPathName. Check what GetCurrentDirectory says.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but after a bit of tinkering GetFullPathName worked. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

The relative path you have is computed  based on your process/run time working directory and not on your static files location in compile time.

Comment: I'm aware that it depends on the current file location, but I have checked this previously, and it is in the correct location. To ensure this, I reset the file location using SetFileLocation() to the intitial position, retrieved via GetFileLocation at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Can you verify what is your CWD via GetWorkingDirectory() ?

Comment: I can't seem to get GetWorkingDirectory to work, but GetCurrentDirectory returns the correct value

Comment: My bad its indeed GetCurrentDirectory, as a debug hint if you hard code the path and provide full path to the image , does the API returns successfully ?

Comment: Yes, I just read a comment above telling me to generate the absolute path name using other functions, so that should work fine

Answer (score 1):

This may be an old post, but having stumbled across this problem (in my case, a header file) and found an answer, here it is:

If referencing a relative path, the first directory is not preceeded by a backslash.

In this example, the line would be:

(HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,"Images\\Mage default.bmp",...